# Herkunft und Verbreitung des Wortes „olei“

Tags: etymology, regional

Ich habe vor einiger Zeit eine Weile in Gießen in Mittelhessen gelebt. Dabei ist mir aufgefallen, dass dort das Wort *olei* (evtl. auch *oleih*, *olai* oder *o-l…* geschrieben) sehr häufig verwendet wird. In der Region um Gießen herum (Marburg, Frankfurt, Fulda, …) und auch in anderen Bundesländern scheint dieses Wort nicht verwendet zu werden, zumindest ist es mir nicht begegnet.

*Olei* wird verwendet, um Begeisterung oder Bewunderung auszudrücken, wenn man etwas Beeindruckendes sieht oder erzählt bekommt, analog zu *Krass!* oder *Wow!* in neudeutscher Sprache.

Wo kommt dieses Wort her und was ist seine ursprüngliche Bedeutung? (Kommt es eventuell aus dem [Manischen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manische_Sprache)? Dies wird in einigen Vierteln von Gießen gesprochen.)

Wird dieses Wort auch in anderen Regionen Deutschlands verwendet?

Comment: Nie gehört. Es wird aber im Wikipedia-Artikel zum Manischen erwähnt, den ich jetzt oben verlinkt habe: „Obgleich in diesen Kontexten häufig die Interjektion _Ulai_ (Ausdruck des Erstaunens; wegen der mangelnden Kodifizierung des Manischen auch _Ulei_, _Olai_, _Orlei_ usw.) dem Manischen zugerechnet wird, konnte dieser etymologische Zusammenhang bisher nicht belegt werden.“

Comment: Ich kenne das als "Ulei" und kann definitiv sagen, dass es im Bereich um Schwalmstadt dann wieder verwendet wird.

Comment: @chirlu: da ausser von Thomas sonst keine weitere Antwort kam, gehe ich davon aus das der Teil den du in deinem Kommentar zitierst wahrscheinlich die korrekte Antwort ist, wenn du es als Antwort formulierst werde ich es akzeptieren.

Answer (score 7):

Ich komme aus dem Raum Frankfurt, und dort verwenden wir - in tiefster Mundart :-) - auch mal den Ausdruck. Ausgesprochen wird das (ich kann leider keine Lautschrift) wie "Ooh Leih" und dann kommen wir auch der Bedeutung schrittweise näher. In der Form wird nämlich das letzte "t" (oder "d") von "Ooh Leit/Leid" verschluckt. Und damit erhalten wir (zumindest für die Hessische Mundart) in etwa als "Übersetzung" ein "Oh Leute!", und daraus folgt dann "Oh, Mann!". Das kann Bewunderung ausdrücken, aber auch das genaue Gegenteil, je nach Kontext, z.B. "Oh, Mann, ist das schlecht!". Ich würde es als allgemeinen Kraftausdruck des Erstaunens bezeichnen - das ist eine besser zutreffende, neutralere Auslegung.

Geschrieben habe ich das noch nicht gesehen, ist ja eine *Mundart*. Insofern möchte ich die verschiedenen Schreibweisen besser nicht kommentieren.

Comment: Ich kenne das ooh leudd aus Frankfurt, bin mir aber ziemlich sicher das es nicht im zusammenhang mit den Giessener Olei steht. Aber danke für die Antwort.